# what is K.eval(loss) in keras tensorflow code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In this keras/tensorflow code:

```
import keras.backend as K

y_pred = model.predict(X)
loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(
                                    K.variable(y_true), 
                                    K.variable(y_pred))
print("K.eval(loss):", K.eval(loss))
```

what does `K.eval(loss)` give you? where can I look this up?

Answer (score 3):

[K.eval](https://keras.io/backend/#eval) evaluates the value of a variable. Therefore, `K.eval(loss)` gives you the value of the crossentropy loss.

Comment: What is the difference between this and `sess.run(loss)`?

Comment: It is exactly the same

Comment: I see. So loss by itself is only the function declaration.

Comment: Right. You are first declaring the loss tensor, and it does not have a value until you evaluate it.

Comment: @DanielMöller it is not exactly the same - only if `sess is K.get_session((loss,))`.

Comment: In 2017 I was a newbie :p -- Today I realized that we don't need session for using Keras (this means I still know almost nothing about session)